# How to add borders to a Pandas styler object?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a data frame, df, as below:

| Name | Day |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Monday |
| John | Thursday |
| Sam | Friday |
| Bob | Monday |
| Katie | Sunday |
| Kyle | Tuesday |
| Katie | Saturday |
| Bob | Wednesday |
| Katie | Sunday |
| Sam | Thursday |
| Joe | Friday |

The following code highlights entire rows given how often a name occurs within the Name Column:

```
cmap = {1: 'green', 2: 'yellow', 3: 'red'}
freq = df['Name'].map(df['Name'].value_counts())
colors = freq.map(cmap).radd('background-color: ')

df.style.apply(lambda s: colors)
```

However when I use .render() in order to convert the styler object to html to send in an email, there is no boarder in the table. How do you keep a boarder when converting a dataframe to a styler object then to an HTML table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the question virtually typed up when I found the answer so I thought I'd do it as a Q&A.

Stringing styles on one after the other when creating the styler object worked well. For example:

```
df.style.apply(lambda s: colors).set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]},
      {"selector": "tbody td", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]},
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]}])
```

Then within the set_table_styles different parameters can be changed to format the boarder.