# how to maintain the look and feel of a table after adding a color

Tags: html, css, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

to my jupyter lab I'm always adding this cell to make a neat clean table look:

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
       border: 1px solid lightgray;
       font-size: 12px;
       font-family: Verdana;
    }
</style>

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [*"123123123"], "B": [*"abcdefghi"]})
```

original result:

[image]

Now I'm wish to highlight row B when the value is h:

```
def style_specific_cell(x):

    c1 = 'background-color: red'    
    c2 = ''
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x['B'] == 'h' #hard coded just for the example
    df1['B'] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
    
    return df1
```

and when running the style:

```
df.style.apply(style_specific_cell, axis=None)
```

I get:

[image]

The results are good but the look and feel is off. I wish to maintain the original result table in terms of the HTML look. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently one can add set_table_styles to define the end result of the table. So an example would be:

```
 df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).set_table_styles(
    [{"selector": "", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]},
      {"selector": "tbody td", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]},
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid")]}])
```

credit to @Jean123 for his/her answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330243/how-to-add-borders-to-a-pandas-styler-object).